# Block title renders but Block content does not, on the same page

Tags: django, django-templates

The `{% block title %}` is being rendered, so **Test** is displayed on the page, and changes when I change whatever is in there. However, no matter what I do with `{% block content %}`, the content does not display on the page.

I would have assumed that either both of them, or none of them would display.

Why would only one block type display and not the other?

```
<!-- templates/registration/password_reset_complete.html -->
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} Test {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div id="content" class="colM">
    <p>We've emailed a new password to the e-mail address you submitted. You should be receiving it shortly.</p>
    <p> You can log in now on the <a href="{% url 'login' %}">log in page</a>.</p>
    <h1>Password reset sent</h1>
    <br class="clear">
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you share your base.html file?

Comment: There is probably no `{% block content %}` in your `base.html`.

Comment: Thanks @C14L, I changed `{% block content %}` to `{% block main %}` as is found in the `base.html` file and it worked!